# SQL server 2008 Virtual Machine. There is insufficient system memory in resource pool 'internal' to run this query

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, vmware

There is insufficient system memory in resource pool 'internal' to run this query. SQL Server 2008 SP3 VMWare VM.

Comment: you need to provide more details about your problem, at this point there is no way to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Your query requires too much space.  The cause depends on the server configuration and the query.  I'd look first for inadvertent cross joins/non equi-joins.

However, your question is way too vague to answer.  I'd suggest you take the opportunity to provide more details.